# regression loop with blocks of dataset

Tags: stata

I have a dataset with three variables and every block has different Sic codes. I need to do for each Sic the same regression: y = mq+r+d

```
y mq r d Sic
x x x x  1
x x x x  1
x x x x  2
x x x x  2
x x x x  3
x x x x  3
```

i tried this way but it does not work:

```
foreach i of local Sic {
reg y mq r d if Sic == `i'
}
```

Comment: Lacks an MCVE, so unclear. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It seems that you have at least 5 variables. Why state otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

"does not work" is notoriously uninformative as an error report. What did Stata do or not do? Were there error messages? In what precise sense did you get what you do not want or not get what you do want?

Nothing in your question shows that you have defined a local macro `Sic` which your syntax needs to work as you wish. That is my strongest guess at the problem.

For an example like yours, the easiest syntax is to use `statsby` or to loop across integers:

```
forval i = 1/3 {
    reg y mq r d if Sic == `i'
}
```

Nevertheless we can't be certain that `Sic` is numeric rather than string. If it's string, you will need different syntax.